# Contour Plot in web browser

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, charts, contour

I need to plot a contour chart in the web browser. It needs to be interactive as well. Does anyone know good javascript library, flash or flex libary to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Flex developer so I can speak to that section of this question at least.  From what I've seen this doesn't exist in Flash/Flex (at least in any open available source) and to a large degree this question is too vague to answer, perhaps link to some example images of what it is you're trying to create.  From doing a Google search of contour chart images I see there's quite a variety of implementations based on different usages.  In general though within Flex there's a datavisualization framework that includes some starting points for doing charting if you're interested in checking that out a bit more here's the link: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part7_DataVis_1.html

Alternatively you could start bit more "from scratch" and use Degrafa as the starting point: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part7_DataVis_1.html

Or just go all the way and do it for real from scratch using the flash drawing primitives, if you have a clear understanding of your goal and the chart isn't expected to be re-used in lots of varying scenarios you may be best off going this route as you'll have the tightest control over the end product.  I did this for building a pseudo 3D bar chart and it was actually easier than expected, I haven't yet but I'll post the code along with some other charts I've made at http://www.shaunhusain.com/charts (need to reboot to linux to get that example, will post within the next 4 hours).

Shaun

Comment: Hello Shaun, thank you very much for the help. Now I'm looking into that data visualization on Flex. What I need to do is to create http://www.steema.com/uploads/gallery/Contour.png kind of a chart. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Hi Ashen, sorry didn't get around to posting that example yet but anyhow I'm gonna have to put this off until tomorrow probably after work but I'll see what I can pull together based on the image shown could you also provide a sample data set, use pastebin or something else to post if need be.

Comment: Okay got the first example posted that's my old chart drawn with flash primitives to get pseudo 3d bar chart, based on what I see here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html I think I could probably pull any of these off with just the drawing primitives aside from the 3D view which looks more challenging but all the 2D one's like yours seem pretty reasonable but please post some sample data set so I know what the data coming in would look like and I can get you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

plotly.js

https://plot.ly/javascript/contour-plots/

https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#contour

```
var data = [ {
        z: [[10, 10.625, 12.5, 15.625, 20],
    [5.625, 6.25, 8.125, 11.25, 15.625],
    [2.5, 3.125, 5.0, 8.125, 12.5],
    [0.625, 1.25, 3.125, 6.25, 10.625],
    [0, 0.625, 2.5, 5.625, 10]],
        type: 'contour'
    }
];

var layout = {
  title: 'Basic Contour Plot'
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```